# javascript convert object to array of objects with key value labels

Tags: javascript

Say i have an object like this..

```
const obj = {
  streaming_tile_x: 608,
  streaming_tile_z: 608,
  global_total_mesh_count: 9776,
  global_total_asset_count: 17831,
  global_total_texture_count: 64055,
  global_total_entity_count: 0,
  global_total_shader_count: 9776,
}
```

How can i convert it to an array of objects like this...

```
const results = [
    { 
        name: "streaming_tile_x", 
        value: 608 
    },
    { 
        name: "streaming_tile_z", 
        value: 608 
    },
    { 
        name: "global_total_mesh_count", 
        value: 9776 
    },
    { 
        name: "global_total_asset_count", 
        value: 17831 
    },
    { 
        name: "global_total_texture_count", 
        value: 64055 
    },
    { 
        name: "global_total_entity_count", 
        value: 0 
    },
    { 
        name: "global_total_shader_count", 
        value: 9776 
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Object.keys(obj).map(key => ({name: key, value: obj[key]}))
```

Comment: great thanks. ill mark as answer when i can

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) with [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and array [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
const obj = {
  streaming_tile_x: 608,
  streaming_tile_z: 608,
  global_total_mesh_count: 9776,
  global_total_asset_count: 17831,
  global_total_texture_count: 64055,
  global_total_entity_count: 0,
  global_total_shader_count: 9776,
};

const result = Object.entries(obj).map(([name, value]) => ({name, value}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `for in` loop to make this new array

```js
const obj = {
  streaming_tile_x: 608,
  streaming_tile_z: 608,
  global_total_mesh_count: 9776,
  global_total_asset_count: 17831,
  global_total_texture_count: 64055,
  global_total_entity_count: 0,
  global_total_shader_count: 9776,
}

let array = []

for (let object in obj) {
  array.push({
    name: object,
    value: obj[object]
  })
}

console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

First catch the object keys then iterate over there.

```js
obj = {
  streaming_tile_x: 608,
  streaming_tile_z: 608,
  global_total_mesh_count: 9776,
  global_total_asset_count: 17831,
  global_total_texture_count: 64055,
  global_total_entity_count: 0,
  global_total_shader_count: 9776,
}

n = Object.keys(obj).map((o) => {
  return {
    name: o,
    value: obj[o]
  }
})

console.log('n', n);
```